# Load JSON data to JQuery DataTables using AJAX Source

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am trying to get data into DataTables from AJAX source as below:

```
$('#DT').DataTable( {
    "paging": false,
    "processing": true,
    "info": false,
    "ajax": 'http://localhost:5000/get_data'
} );
```

It's working when the server provides data in this format as below:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      1,
      "0FL0BW1MA",
      "2018-03-24 15:00",
      "Lisbon ,Lisboa ,Portugal",
      "CMA CGM GEORG FORSTER",
      "ADALV",
      "2018-05-08 02:00",
      "ADENC"
    ]
  ]
}
```

But the actual server sends response in JSON key:value format as follows:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "containers": 4, 
      "destination_port": "2018-05-08 02:00", 
      "eta": "CMA CGM GEORG FORSTER", 
      "etd": "2018-03-24 15:00", 
      "loading_port": "Lisbon ,Lisboa ,Portugal", 
      "vessels": "0FL0BW1MA"
    }    
  ]
}
```

So, My question is how can I load the actual JSON data to data table?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually, It would be great if I could use the existing API. Otherwise, I should ask.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Hopefully the answer I added below helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide the content of the #DT table. But my guess is that you already populated it with TH's?

if that is the case you should be able to do something like this

```js
// This is the data you get from the server
var strData = {
  "data": [
      {
      "containers": 4, 
      "destination_port": "2018-05-08 02:00", 
      "eta": "CMA CGM GEORG FORSTER", 
      "etd": "2018-03-24 15:00", 
      "loading_port": "Lisbon ,Lisboa ,Portugal", 
      "vessels": "0FL0BW1MA"
      }    
  ]
}

// Creating the new array according to your specifications
var arrData = [];
for (var key in strData.data) {
    if (!strData.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    var obj = strData.data[key];
    var tmpArr = []
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
        tmpArr.push(obj[prop]); 
    }
    arrData.push(tmpArr);
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').dataTable( {
        "data": arrData,
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    containers
                </th>
                <th>
                    destination_port
                </th>
                <th>
                    eta
                </th>
                <th>
                    etd
                </th>
                <th>
                    loading_port
                </th>
                <th>
                    vessels
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

You can however provide datatables with an array of the columns instead of defining them in html, which i would probably do. I think it would make things more dynamic.

--- Updated code when using the ajax function in DataTables

First we need to make a function for converting the json

```
function convertArray(json) {
    var arrData = [];
    for (var key in json.data) {
        if (!json.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        var obj = json.data[key];
        var tmpArr = []
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
            tmpArr.push(obj[prop]); 
        }
        arrData.push(tmpArr);
    }
    return arrData;
}
```

I have never used DataTables before but their documentation states that one can use dataSrc to pass in a custom function. Lets try using it like so

```
$('#DT').DataTable( {
    "paging": false,
    "processing": true,
    "info": false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "http://localhost:5000/get_data",
        "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
            return convertArray(json);
        }
    }
} );
```

This should pass the json response to our function and convert the data.

Comment: I tried this one. I am getting an empty array in the result. What might be the issue?

Comment: In order to use the script we will have to make it into a function, so that we can pass data from the ajax response and get the result you need. I edited the post with a new function and the changes you need to make to your existing script in order to make it work. - fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not possible for you to amend the response coming from the server, which would be the best solution by far, then you can amend the response from an array of objects to a nested array by using `map()`, like this:

```js
var source = {
  "data": [{
    "containers": 4,
    "destination_port": "2018-05-08 02:00",
    "eta": "CMA CGM GEORG FORSTER",
    "etd": "2018-03-24 15:00",
    "loading_port": "Lisbon ,Lisboa ,Portugal",
    "vessels": "0FL0BW1MA"
  }]
};

var output = {
  data: source .data.map(function(item) {
    return [
      item.containers,
      item.vessels,
      item.etd,
      item.loading_port,
      item.eta,
      'ADALV', // not clear where this value is in the source 
      item.destination_port,
      'ADENC' // not clear where this value is in the source 
    ]
  })
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This could be good. It would be great if you give any idea to load the mapped data to DataTables. Please see the first portion of code at my question.

Comment: You can use `$.ajax` to retrieve the data from your API, put it through the logic above then apply it to the DataTable by using the `data` property: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html